# Sending FormData from ReactJs to NodeJs controller using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have JS object in the following format which i want to send at backend. I have implemented some code but at nodeJs controller it says `hotel is undefined`. My written code is following:

```
let hotel = new FormData();
hotel.append('name', data.append);
hotel.append('slug', data.slug);
hotel.append('logo', data.logo);
hotel.append('coverAvatar', data.coverAvatar);
hotel.append('designs', [{ name: `${+new Date()}`, url: localStorage.getItem('initialDesign') }])
hotel.append('products', [...selectedVariants]);

axios.post(`${baseURL}/hotel`, { hotel },{
  headers: {
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('_AUTH_TOKEN'),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }})
  .then(response => {
    console.log({ response });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err);
  })
```

I'm using multipart/form-data because logo and coverAvatar are output of `<input type='file' />`

**My data Format**

```
{
  "name": "preshan hotel 2",
  "logo": {file},
  "coverAvatar": {file},
  "romms": [{
    "name": "tempDesign",
    "url": "https://picsum.photos/600/800"
  }], 
  "facilities": [
    { "facilityId": "61ceb3931b1b68fe90827f23", "facilityMappings": ["61ceb39b1b1b68fe90827f2c", "61ceb39b1b1b68fe90827f41"] },
    { "facilityId": "61ceb3ca1b1b68fe90827f47", "facilityMappings": ["61ceb3ca1b1b68fe90827f50","61ceb3ca1b1b68fe90827f58", "61ceb3ca1b1b68fe90827f56"] },
    { "facilityId": "61ceb3e41b1b68fe90827f5d", "facilityMappings": ["61ceb3e41b1b68fe90827f5f"]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have to handle multipart forms with multer or formidable in the backend.

Comment: @UmerAbbas. that's a typo in quuestion - not in code- thanks for pointing. fixing now

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV can you please give an example

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV am I sending the data correctly ?

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer] This page shows you necessary examples

Comment: You can't send FormData object as a property of another object

Comment: @charlietfl so what is the right way ?

Comment: There are other issues also. You are passing arrays and objects directly in the appends. Instead of passing to axios as `{hotel}` it would just be `hotel` and back end would look for the various keys you created

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your formdata directly instead of passing an object.

In your example it would look like this:

```
...
axios.post(`${baseURL}/hotel`, hotel,{
...
```